# How do I find token values for custom profile property names in the member directory module templates in DNN?

Tags: templates, directory, token, dotnetnuke, profile

I'm trying to figure out how to turn profile property names into tokens I can use in the member directory.

The problem seems to arise when I try to use profile properties that have multi-word names (names with spaces in them).

I have a property named "Telephone" that I can get to appear by using "ProfileProperties().Telephone". I have another property named "Position Title" that doesn't work if I use "ProfileProperties().PositionTitle" or "ProfileProperties().Position_Title".  I tried just using "PositionTitle()" and just "PositionTitle", too, but no dice.

I posted this in the DNN forums and "ask a question" too, but responses there seem to be a bit...delayed.

Does anyone know if there's a predetermined method or formula for turning profile property names into valid token values for use with the ProfileProperties() method in the member directory templates, or, failing that, if there's a different way to display custom profile properties?

Comment: After digging through the source code, it appears that the code where profile properties get set in the Member Directory module is javascript using Knockout.

Comment: So, while I don't have an answer to the above, exactly, it appears that adding profile properties with property names devoid of whitespace gives usable tokens.  Then you can add a value in the localization settings that is formatted, etc.